# Stack Overflow error : Passing struct to function vc++

Tags: pointers, visual-c++, structure, stack-overflow

I am working with VC++ for some months now. I have never come across 'Stack Overflow' error until today when I try to pass a structure to function.

This is my code:

```
int bReadFileData(string sFile, struct FILE_DATA *File_Data);
const int MAX_CRASH_FILE_SIZE = 100000;
struct FILE_DATA
{
    int SIZE;
    int GOOD[MAX_CRASH_FILE_SIZE];
    int BAD[MAX_CRASH_FILE_SIZE];
};

int bReadFileData(string sFile, struct FILE_DATA *File_Data)
{

File_Data->SIZE = 0;
if(PathFileExists(Convert.StringToCstring(sFile)) == 1)
{
    string sLine = "";
    int iLine = 0;
    std::ifstream File(sFile);
    while(getline(File, sLine))
    {
        if(sLine.find(":") != std::string::npos)
        {
            File_Data->CRASH_VALUES[iLine] = sLine.substr(0, sLine.find(":"));
            File_Data->CRASH_VALUES[iLine] = sLine.substr(sLine.find(":") + 1, sLine.length());
        }
        else
        {
            File_Data->CRASH_VALUES[iLine] = (sLine);
        }
        iLine++;
    }
    File_Data->SIZE = iLine;
}
return 1;
}
```

`

From main function I am calling below method.

```
void ReadFiles()
{
    FILE_DATA Files[3];
    bReadFileData("C:\\Test1.txt", &Files[0]);
    bReadFileData("C:\\Test2.txt", &Files[1]);
    bReadFileData("C:\\Test3.txt", &Files[2]);
}
```

Is there any thing wrong in this code? Why stack overflow error is thrown(as soon as it enter ReadFiles()?

Comment: Your struct is 800K large. Three of them take up 2M+. Default stack size is 1M - `FILE_DATA[3]` can't possibly fit on it. Avoid placing large variables on the stack, allocate them on the heap instead. I also question the wisdom of defining such a large structure to begin with; consider using members of type `std::vector<int>` or similar, in place of huge fixed-size arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why stack overflow error is thrown(as soon as it enter ReadFiles()?

That's because FILE_DATA[3] allocates too much bytes for stack memory. The size of stack memory is around 1Mb by default, while size of FILE_DATA[3] is around 2.4Mb (~ 800,000 x 3 bytes).

If you use the struct with large size, try to use heap memory as follows:

```
void ReadFiles()
{
  FILE_DATA* Files = new FILE_DATA[3];
  bReadFileData("C:\\Test1.txt", &Files[0]);
  bReadFileData("C:\\Test2.txt", &Files[1]);
  bReadFileData("C:\\Test3.txt", &Files[2]);
  delete [] Files;
  Files = nullptr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not just bad, but terrible design. You should:

- Use `vector` for `GOOD` and `BAD`
- Use `vector.push_back` instead of `File_Data->CRASH_VALUES[iLine]` assignment.
- Use dynamic allocation (if you don't use `vector`). If you must use dynamic allocation, I recommend using `make_unique` (C++11/14) instead of `new`, like this:

---

```
void ReadFiles()
    {
      auto Files = std::make_unique<FILE_DATA[]>(2);
      bReadFileData("C:\\Test1.txt", &Files[0]);
      bReadFileData("C:\\Test2.txt", &Files[1]);
      bReadFileData("C:\\Test3.txt", &Files[2]);
      // delete [] Files; - DONT NEED
      // Files = nullptr;
    }
```

If you can simply use `vector`, you can have this:

```
void ReadFiles()
{
  FILE_DATA Files[3];
  ...
```